# Will adding RAM improve my PC performance when using Android studio?

Tags: memory, performance

I know this question is asked many times but looking at the following data, what do you think adding RAM will really help me?

This is the two pics of my Task manager when I was working in android studio. The run process is so slow in android studio and everything get hangs up.

- **My PC**: HP Compaq 6005 pro small form factor.
- **RAM**: 4GB (DDR3)
- **Processor**: 3 GHZ
- **HDD**: 500 GB

Can I improve this, or should I buy a new one for programming.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It certainly will, running anything with just 4 GB of RAM nowadays is painful and with Android Studio it's just masochistic torture. It's quite an old PC though, so don't expect miracles.

Comment: what if i raised it to 16 Gb?

Comment: The processor can use 16GB, but that's assuming you're running a 64-bit OS. You'd also benefit from an SSD … but there's a limit to how much you'll gain on such an old machine.

Comment: your system is too old. I would prioritize getting a modern system with at least 16 gb ram for android development.

Answer (score -1):

In my professional opinion, the CPU which is quoted on the manufacturer's website is much too old to do work on in 2021.

```
  AMD Sempron 140 Processor (2.7-GHz, 1MB L2 cache, HT bus 3.0)
```

Perhaps your build includes a different cpu, because you stated a different frequency. Anyway, the Sempron 140 is over ten years old and has roughly 1/4 the power of a more recent intel CPU from 5-6-7 years ago.

hp specs: https://support.hp.com/ee-en/document/c01865086

<blogpost-opinion>

If you can afford it, get a modern AMD cpu such as

```
Ryzen 3 2200G €141
Ryzen 5 3600 €190
Ryzen 5 5600X €344
```

Or get a used one for cheaper. If you want to buy a used CPU that is older than 3 years, go for Intel. You will probably be able to find something like an i7 7700 relatively cheaply, depending on your location and budget. Today (in 2021), I would not consider anything that is slower than a i7 4790k as appropriate for working. If you are really in a bind money-wise, then find a used server-oriented intel xeon CPU that is 4-6 years old.

I also don't consider any mac-book-pro as appropriate for working, or almost any laptop. Essentially - anything that runs on a battery is designed to conserve energy and not to yield maximum performance. Same goes for mini-computer builds, like the one you are asking about.

You can compare relative cpu-value-price on https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/ . It's not flawless, but serves well for general orientation.

</blogpost-opinion>

Adding memory will help because "compressed memory" in windows 10 basically means you are "swapping out to disk" or "using the page file" which is also on disk.
To answer your initial question, anything below 16 gb ram is a joke for development. Above 24 gb may be overkill.

The output from the task manager suggests that you *need* to add at least an additional 12-gb of ram to your system.

ref: https://www.howtogeek.com/319933/what-is-memory-compression-in-windows-10/

Comment: hahaha, someone down-voted my answer. how about you provide an alternative answer first?